# I have to fill an array with filenames, in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, string, filenames

I have to fill an array with filenames. It is a local folder, with a lot of files inside, and i need that the names of files "go inside" the array. 
fileNames[0] = australia.jpg
fileNames[1] = italy.jpg
and so on.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
 var getFilesNames = function(){
      var folderPath = Folder ("C:\Users\Giulio\Desktop");
      var toteTempFiles = toteTempPath.getFiles();
      var namesArr = [];
      for(var i=0; i<toteTempFiles.length; i++){
        var thisFile = toteTempFiles[i];
        myNames.push(thisFile.name);
      }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried anything? can you show some code?

Comment: "Gimme teh codez plzzz ^_^"

Comment: I tried some codes finded on the net, but nothing.

Comment: No, i would like to have the Explained Code, i am a students, i searched on google, but someone says that JavaScript cant do this, so i would like to know if it is true.

Comment: How is it not working? 'toteTempPath' appears to be undeclared that should throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as im aware its not possible to go snooping around a users file system, that would be quite a large security concern.

However with the new File API it is possible for the user to give you access to certain files, allowing you to get info on them and upload them. However this does involve the user having to perform an action.

So changing your requirements slightly you could do this:

```
<input type="file" id="input" multiple />
```

And JS

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

function handleFiles() {
    var fileList = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        fileList.push(this.files[i].name);   
    }

    console.log(fileList);
}
```

Essentially you have an input which the user interacts with. When its value changes, selected some files, the `onchange` handler fires giving you information on the files selected.

Its important to note that `this.files` is not an array but an array like object, like the `arguments` variable. So you can't `map` or do `forEach` on it.

So in your use use it would change slightly to the user having to select all the files in your needed folder. Then you can continue to get all the info on them you need.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q97dgjso/

And some resources that may help you: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: Thanks man! It works, i dont know if it is possible, but i would like to set a default directory and automatically select every file inside, you know if it is possible? Anyway i am going to study the FIle API, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Giulio As i said i don't think that's possible and if it is it would be a huge security risk. Would you want a website being able to just randomly select files from somewhere in your filesystem?